# Finding the explicit formula for the sum: $\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}(-1)^mf_n(kn -\frac{ m (m + 1)}{2})$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, summation

I am looking for the explicit formula for the 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}(-1)^mf_n\Big(kn -\frac{m (m + 1)}{2}\Big)$$
where the $f_n$ is a custom function, with condition 
$f_n(k)=0, k<0$ or $k>n-1$.
Initially it looked very simple, but I really stuck with this.

I can give the Mathematica command to calculate this, just in order to help with testing:

`g[n_, k_] := Table[If[k*n - m (m + 1)/2 >= 0 && k*n - m (m + 1)/2 <= (n - 1), f[(k*n - m (m + 1)/2)]*(-1)^m, Nothing] , {m, 1, n - 1}]
Table[Total[Flatten[Table[g[n, k], {k, 1, (n - 1)/2}]]], {n, 1, 100}]`

and few basic elements:

$
1: 0,\\ 
2: 0, \\
3: f_3(0)-f_3(2), \\
4: f_4(1)-f_4(3), \\
5: f_5(0)+f_5(2)-2f_5(4),\\ 
6: -f_6(0)+f_6(2)+f_6(3)-f_6(5)\\
$

Comment: $$k = \lceil \frac{m (m+1)}{2n} \rceil$$

Comment: Thank you for comment, could you please just detalize a bit.